# space-between and align left and right items to the edges

Tags: css, flexbox

I am working on this project https://launcherspace.wpengine.com/ , the header is built with flexbox, space-between, but the items behave like space-around, here I need the logo to be at the extreme left and the social icons to be at the extreme-right

I have tried align-self: flex-start, but it aligns vertically, tried justify-self and all the solutions, but nothing works

Comment: Check the pseudo-elements in your code.